# Ensure the expanding form is visible in the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm putting together an event invite email and I'm having some difficulty in ensuring an expanded box appears in the middle of the viewport.
I have a number of locations (19) where the event is being held and I want the attendees to click on a location which opens up a form for them to complete. The problem is the expanded form jumps to the top of the page and is obscured by a top banner.

I have researched this but not found a solution. I'm fairly new to JavaScript (I come from a design background).
Thanks for all in advance if any one can help (or guide to me where I can look for a solution).

I have copied in the html code. I'm not sure how useful this will be. I could post a link to all the code, in github but I don't think this is good practice?

```html
<!-- 1. Newcastle -->
<div class="set" id="newcastle">
  <a href="#event_table_new">
    Newcastle <span class="light">(Tuesday 12 April)</span>
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Jesmond Dene House, Jesmond Dene Road
    <br>Newcastle-upon-Tyne NE2 2EY</p>

    <div class="col-sm-3 radio-buttons" id="event_table_New">
      <!-- // Radio buttons -->
      <form>
        <label class="session">Session</label>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadiosNew1" value="option1"> Morning
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadiosNew2" value="option2">Afternoon
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadiosNew3" value="option3">All-day
          </label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- col-sm-3 -->

    <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputName_New">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName_New" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputCompany_New">Company</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputCompany_New" placeholder="Company">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail_New">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail_New" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputTelephone_New">Telephone</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTelephone_New" placeholder="Telephone">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Dietary requirements</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- End of sm 9 col -->
  </div>
  <!-- End of text class -->
</div>
<!-- End of Newcastle set class -->
```